# Calendar View Android 2

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to make a meal planner for a cooking app I'm doing

I have the following code

calendar_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Static CalendarView" />

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Calendar_View.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Calendar_View extends Activity {

CalendarView cal;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_view);

    cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);

    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                        int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Selected Date is\n\n"
                            +dayOfMonth+" : "+month+" : "+year ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calendar_view, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I get the following error message

> "Error:(37, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable menu"

I've looked around on the internet but cannot find a similar problem, I know I'm missing something but don't know what

Does anyone know what I'm missing or how to fix the problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`calendar_view` is a layout, not a menu, so `R.menu.calendar_view` wouldn't exist. `R.layout.calendar_view` would exist, but you can't inflate that with a `MenuInflater` -- you're already doing that correctly in your `onCreate()`. You either need to create a menu xml, or remove the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` call.